# Recursively finding a path on a 2d array [Java]

Tags: java, recursion

I want to write a programm in java that finds a path on a 2d Array with recursion.
The 2d Array named "gitter" consists of Objects of the type 'field'. 
Every field will be initialized with a random number in the range of 100-999. If a field was initialized with a number, in which one of the digits is a prime, it is a "trap". The fields can be imagined as squares, so i can move only in 4 directions:

```
public class Field {

int number;
boolean visited;

Field() {
    Random rn = new Random();
    this.number = rn.nextInt((999+1) - 100) + 100;
    this.visited = false;
}

boolean isTrap() {
    String str = String.valueOf(number);
    if(str.contains("2") | str.contains("3") | str.contains("5") | str.contains("7")) {
        return true;
    } return false;
  }    
}
```

The start-field and the end-field of the path shall have a manhattan-distance of more than 2. The problem so far is the recursion. The more i think about it, the if cases in it are just getting longer and longer. I added also a boolean variable "visited", for not visiting the same field twice, but no success. Is the while-loop necessary for the recursion? If not (what i guess), what is the easiest way to make the recursion stop, after i found a path? i tried it with and without a while-loop, but couldn't find any solution.

```
public class Gitter {

Field[][] gitter = new Field[10][10];
List<Field> path = new ArrayList<Field>();

public Field[] getStartAndGoal() {
    boolean notFound = true;
    Field[] startGoal = new Field[2];
    while(notFound) {   
        Random x0 = new Random();
        Random y0 = new Random();
        Random x1 = new Random();
        Random y1 = new Random();
        int row0 = x0.nextInt((9)+1);
        int line0 = y0.nextInt((9)+1);
        int row1 = x1.nextInt((9)+1);
        int line1 = y1.nextInt((9)+1);
        int distance = Math.abs(row1-row0) + Math.abs(line1-line0);
        if(distance>2){
            if(gitter[row0][line0].isTrap() == false && gitter[row1][line1].isTrap() ==false) {
                notFound = false;
            Field start = gitter[row0][line0];
            Field goal = gitter[row1][line1];
            startGoal[0] = start;
            startGoal[1] = goal;
            }                                              
        }
    }
   return startGoal; 
}

public boolean findPath(Field start, Field goal) {


    boolean solved = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if(gitter[i][j].equals(start)) {
                gitter[i][j].visited=true;                            
                while(solved==false){
                    if((i+1)<10 && gitter[i+1][j].isTrap()==false && gitter[i+1][j].visited == false && findPath(gitter[i+1][j], goal)){
                        gitter[i+1][j].visited = true;
                        path.add(gitter[i+1][j]);
                        return true;
                    }
                    if((i-1)>0 && gitter[i-1][j].isTrap()==false && gitter[i-1][j].visited == false && findPath(gitter[i-1][j], goal)){
                        gitter[i-1][j].visited = true;
                        path.add(gitter[i-1][j]);
                        return true;
                    }
                    if((j+1)<10 && gitter[i][j+1].isTrap()==false && gitter[i][j+1].visited == false && findPath(gitter[i][j+1], goal)){
                        gitter[i][j+1].visited = true;
                        path.add(gitter[i][j+1]);
                        return true;
                    }
                    if((j-1)>10 && gitter[i][j-1].isTrap()==false && gitter[i][j-1].visited == false && findPath(gitter[i][j-1], goal)){
                        gitter[i][j-1].visited = true;
                        path.add(gitter[i][j-1]);
                        return true;
                    }
                    for(i=0; i<path.size(); i++) {
                        if(path.get(i).equals(goal)){
                            solved = true;
                            break;                                                                                               
                        }
                    }
                }                                      
            }
        }
    } return false;      
}
```

Does anybody got a hint for me?

Comment: Should you minimize/maximize the total count of the path cells?

Comment: No its not about minimizing or maximizing the path. Right now i just wanna find one possible solution, doesn't matter if minimized or maximized.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the problem, there are many variables that aren't necessarily too important to consider yet would allow me to create a simple solution quicker. If you use concepts from my solution, just take notes that there are a variety of restraints completely ignored which can easily be implemented.

### Recursion

Typically recursion is used to replace the iterative behaviour of loops. With this problem you want to search every possible path if there exists a path that can take you from point A to point B, or up until you have determined there exists a path.

> The more i think about it, the if cases in it are just getting longer and longer

Easy. Create a helper method that does the calculation for you so that you avoid repetitive use of the same code.

> Is the while-loop necessary for the recursion?

I'm not entirely sure what you're doing with your loops, but it would definitely be possible (and much more elegant) to do away with loops altogether for this solution.

> what is the easiest way to make the recursion stop, after i found a path?

Once you have found a solution, return true. The previous recursive step will receive a true value and then understand that somewhere along the line you have reached the end so it too should return true. This is where the *recursive* aspect can produce such an elegant solution.

### Solution

```
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        int n = 10;
        int[][] map = new int[n][n]; // Generate random data however you want
        boolean[][] visited = new boolean[n][n]; // Defaults to false
        int[2] start = new int[]{0,0}; // Top left corner
        int[2] end = new int[]{n-1, n-1}; // Bottom right corner

        boolean path = pathExists(map, visited, start, end);
    }

    public static boolean pathExists(int[][] map, boolean[][] visited, int[] current, int[] end) {
        int x = current[0];
        int y = current[1];
        // If not in bounds, not a valid route
        if (!inBounds(map, visited, current)) return false;
        // If this is the end, return true!
        if (current[0] == end[0] && current[1] == end[1]) return true;

        // Attempt each cardinal direction. If you find a return, return true
        if (pathExists(map, markPresent(visited, current), new int[]{x-1,y}, end)) return true;
        if (pathExists(map, markPresent(visited, current), new int[]{x+1,y}, end)) return true;
        if (pathExists(map, markPresent(visited, current), new int[]{x,y+1}, end)) return true;
        if (pathExists(map, markPresent(visited, current), new int[]{x,y-1}, end)) return true;
        // There is no solution down this path    
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean[][] markPresent(boolean[][] visited, int[] current) {
        // Make a deep copy - Is needed to prevent interferance
        boolean[][] copy = new boolean[visited.length][visited[0].length];
        for (int i = 0; i < copy.length; i++)
            copy[i] = Arrays.copyOf(visited[i], visited[i].length);
        // Mark where you currently are
        copy[current[0]][current[1]] = true;
        return copy;
    }

    public static boolean inBounds(int[][] map, boolean[][] visited, int[] position) {
        int x = position[0];
        int y = position[1];
        // Make sure it is within the bounds of the map
        if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= map.length || y >= map.length) return false;
        // Check if the current block is a barrier
        if (isBarrier(map, position)) return false;
        // If you have visited this path before, don't do it again
        if (visited[x][y]) return false;

        // Otherwise, check the path!
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isBarrier(int[][] map, int[] position) {
        // Return your definition of a barrier (I used modulo 10 for testing
    }
```

I've done minimal testing, so if you can see any glearing issues feel free to leave a comment.

From what I can gather, you are wanting to detect whether a path exists between to points. If you are wanting to detect the shortest distance (using the Manhatten metric), instance of returning boolean values you could return integer value. If you want to find the path itself, you can return an array of points and recursively append all points to another array. Here's a modified version that finds the shortest path:

```
public static ArrayList<int[]> findDistance(int[][] map, boolean[][] visited, int[] current, int[] end) {
    int x = current[0];
    int y = current[1];
    ArrayList<int[]> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    ret.add(current);

    if (!inBounds(map, visited, current)) return new ArrayList<>(); // Return empty array
    if (current[0] == end[0] && current[1] == end[1]) return ret; // Return current location

    ArrayList<ArrayList<int[]>> paths = new ArrayList<>();
    paths.add(findDistance(map, markPresent(visited, current), new int[]{x-1,y}, end));
    paths.add(findDistance(map, markPresent(visited, current), new int[]{x+1,y}, end));
    paths.add(findDistance(map, markPresent(visited, current), new int[]{x,y+1}, end));
    paths.add(findDistance(map, markPresent(visited, current), new int[]{x,y-1}, end));

    // Find the shortest path that leads somewhere
    paths.removeIf((ArrayList<int[]> data) -> data.size() == 0);
    paths.sort(Comparator.comparing(ArrayList::size));

    // If the size of the paths is 0, no path was found
    if (paths.size() == 0) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    } else {
        //Append the found path to the current location and return the list
        ret.addAll(paths.get(0));
        return ret;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I had a terrible feeling I had forgotten something obvious - I had. You will need to clone the visited array so that you don't interfere with each recursive step. I've added a method to do that.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i added a function for finding a start and an endpoint (returned in form of an array), to make it more comprehensible what i've done here.

Comment: @JensOttmann That segment of code would, imo, be outside the scope of what I thought the question was. From what I understand, you are looking to use recursion to detect whether there is a path between two points (regardless of how you create these points).

Comment: Thats right. The map also doesn't consist of enumerated primitive data types. It is a 2d Array of Objects of type 'field'. I get start and end point with the method 'getStartAndGoal()', which is returning them as an array. Then these fields can be used in the findPath(), which shall find a possible path between these two fields.

Comment: @JensOttmann I'm not sure I'm following what you were wanting. If you are looking for the actual path, I have added that code but the other stuff you mention is really just restrictions that you can add as you see fit (The answer is more about the concept).

Answer (score -1):

Adding some extra things to make things easier:

- `start` and `goal` are attributes of Gitter class
- `findPath` has been divided in tho methods, one public and another private

### Code

```
public class Gitter {
    Field[][] gitter = new Field[10][10];
    List<Field> path = new ArrayList<Field>();

    private Field start = null;
    private Field goal = null;

    // i've omited initializing too

    public boolean findPath(Field start, Field goal) {
        this.start = start;
        this.goal = goal;
        // Instead of having one recursive method, I divided it in two, one public and another private
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                if(gitter[i][j].equals(start)) {
                    return findPath(i,j);
                }
            }
        } return false;      
    }

    /*
     * Check if available path exist from Field [i][j]
     */
    private boolean findPath(int i, int j){

        boolean solved = false;

        // This check makes if-else chain cleaner 
        if(i < 0 || i >= 10 || j < 0 || j >= 10){
            return false;
        }
        // Don't check already visited cells
        if(!gitter[i][j].visited){
            gitter[i][j].visited=true;

            // If its possible to have a trap in goal Field, this check must be first
            if(gitter[i][j].equals(goal)){
                path.add(gitter[i][j]);
                return true;
            }

            // If start Field mustn't be a trap, first condition should be removed
            if(!gitter[i][j].equals(start) && gitter[i][j].isTrap()){
                return false;
            }

            // Down
            if(findPath(i+1,j)){
                solved = true;
            }
            // Up
            else if(findPath(i-1,j)){
                solved = true;
            }
            // Right
            else if(findPath(i,j+1)){
                solved = true;
            }
            // Left
            else if(findPath(i,j-1)){
                solved = true;
            }

            // If any direction check found a path, this cell is part of that path
            if(solved){
                path.add(gitter[i][j]);
            }

            return solved;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I've tried with small numbers (from 1  to 9) and it should work

This one can not be a perfect nor efficient solution, but I've tried to make code **easier to read and understand**. I think with this kind of recursive problems that's a point to be highly considered.

Comment: Thanks, but my Path Array still stays empty. But thank you for the nice readable answer which refers at least to my code. PS.: I didn't gave you a the downvote.

Comment: It's not empty for me. When a path is available, the method returns true, and path contains the numbers involved in such path. PS:thanks for clarifying ;)

Comment: @JensOttmann Also have in mind this. With large numbers, its quite probable to have any of those forbidden numbers in. This fact often causes to not have any path available. This could be a reason why your path array is empty. Try with smaller numbers or reduce the set of forbidden ones.